# Is there any benefit to using LINQ to get the first (and only) element in IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any significant difference between these two lines?

```
var o = xmlFile.Descendants("SomeElement").ElementAt(0).Value;
```

And:

```
var o = xmlFile.Descendants("SomeElement").First().Value;
```

`XmlFile` is an `XDocument` object, and `Descendants(XName name)` returns `IEnumerable<XElement>`.

I know `First();` will throw an exception if the collection is empty and you might want to use `FirstOrDefault();` but that's fine in this case; I already validate my `XDocument` object against an `XmlSchemaSet`, so I know the element exists. I suppose directly accessing `Value` would throw an exception either way if the collection was empty, as `ElementAt(0)` wouldn't return anything either.

But yea; I, obviously, don't like adding `using` directives if I don't need to. Is there any reason one might want to use LINQ in this case? I can't imagine there's any real performance difference in either case.

I ask because the user is able to upload a zip file containing any number of XML files that need to be processed. 1 "record" per XML file.

**EDIT**: What my original question was going to be was "How do you get the first element from IEnumerable without adding `using System.Linq;` then I found the `ElementAt`, not realizing they were both part of LINQ.

So I guess really what I want to know is, would there be a difference between either snippet above and this:

```
var descendants = xmlFile.Descendants("SomeElement");
var enumerator = descendants.GetEnumerator();
var node = (enumerator.MoveNext()) ? enumerator.Current : null;
```

I'd definitely say LINQ is much more readable, and for that alone is probably worth using. But again, the user can upload I think up to a 10 MB zip file and each of these XML files ranges from about 2 kilobytes to 10 kilobytes, depending on which schema it is. So that's a good number of files.

Comment: `First` and `ElementAt` are both extension methods defined on `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

Comment: Oh. Well. Look at that. Hm. Originally my question was going to simply be "How to get the value of the first element returned by `Descendants`?" but I found a handful of solutions that just used `First()`; wasn't sure what other way it could be done.

Comment: Also, when both snippets are equivalent and have essentially the same performance, you should pick the option that you feel is easiest to read.

Comment: @sab669 Also, if that's supposed to be the _only_ element, you may want to consider using `Single` instead of `First` since that better communicates your expectations.  If it's possible for there to be multiple items (and you only want the first) then I'd go with `First`.

Comment: Thanks, @Kyle, I wasn't aware of `Single()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers here point out that both options you've presented actually use LINQ. But your updated question asks if this is equivalent to the original LINQ call:

```
var descendants = xmlFile.Descendants("SomeElement");
var enumerator = descendants.GetEnumerator();
var node = (enumerator.MoveNext()) ? enumerator.Current : null;
```

Well, no, not quite. Firstly, note that the `IEnumerator<T>` implements `IDisposable`, but your code is never going to call `Dispose` (although I doubt that would actually have any affect in this case). Secondly, your code handles empty data sets differently from either of those LINQ methods (your implementation is more like `FirstOrDefault`). A more equivalent version would be:

```
XElement node;
using (var enumerator = xmlFile.Descendants("SomeElement").GetEnumerator()) 
{
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) 
    {
       throw new Exception(...); 
    }
    node = enumerator.Current;
}
```

Or without the `using`:

```
XElement node;
var enumerator = xmlFile.Descendants("SomeElement").GetEnumerator();
try {
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) { throw new Exception(...); }
    node = enumerator.Current;
} finally {
    enumerator.Dispose();
}
```

But in truth, we don't need the `Enumerator` at all. We can get rid of the call to `Descendants` like this:

```
var n = xmlFile.FirstNode;
var node = n as XElement;
while (node == null && n != null) 
{
    node = (n = n.NextNode) as XElement;
}
while (node != null &&  node.Name != "SomeElement") 
{
    node = (n = node.FirstNode ?? node.NextNode ?? node.Parent?.NextNode) as XElement;
    while (node == null && n != null) 
    {
        node = (n = n.NextNode) as XElement;
    }
}
if (node == null) 
{
    throw new Exception(""); 
}
```

Now, if you profile this, you'll find some *marginal* performance boost with the more complex solutions. Here's the results of a fairly basic benchmark I put together (first column is without compiler optimizations, second column is with compiler optimizations):

```
Method       Mean (/o-)   Mean (/o+)
First()      0.1468333    0.1414340
ElementAt()  0.1452045    0.1419018
No Linq      0.1334992    0.1259622
While Loop   0.0895821    0.0693819
```

However, saving a few processor cycles usually isn't your biggest concern in enterprise-level applications. Given the typical costs for maintaining code, you should generally try to optimize for readability, and in my opinion, this is a *lot* easier to read:

```
var node = xmlFile.Descendants("SomeElement").First();
```

Comment: Thanks! My mistake for not doing all the research when I first posted the question, but having updated it this is the answer I was looking for. I know what you meant, but FYI you do have a tiny error on the last line of your post; `var XElement node = ...` :)

Comment: @sab669 Yeah I noticed a few problems with my original implementation. I've updated my answer and provided a comparison of the various solutions for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

Check the source. Both `ElementAt` and `First` are extension methods defined on [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs) (as noted by [Lee](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs)  in the question comments).

#### Update

I included the implementation for `Single` as well, as it was discussed it would be a better option for this specific problem. Fundamentally this comes down to readability and exceptions that are thrown, as they all use the same way of accessing the first element.

```
    public static TSource First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
        if (list != null) {
            if (list.Count > 0) return list[0];
        }
        else {
            using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
                if (e.MoveNext()) return e.Current;
            }
        }
        throw Error.NoElements();
    }


    public static TSource ElementAt<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int index) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
        if(list != null) return list[index];
        if (index < 0) throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("index");
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            while (true) {
                if (!e.MoveNext()) throw Error.ArgumentOutOfRange("index");
                if (index == 0) return e.Current;
                index--;
            }
        }
    }

    public static TSource Single<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
        if (list != null) {
            switch (list.Count) {
                case 0: throw Error.NoElements();
                case 1: return list[0];
            }
        }
        else {
            using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
                if (!e.MoveNext()) throw Error.NoElements();
                TSource result = e.Current;
                if (!e.MoveNext()) return result;
            }
        }
        throw Error.MoreThanOneElement();
    }
```

Comment: Stupid question but is there an easy way to access the source code from the MSDN documentation? I occasionally see people suggest looking at it on SO but I always forget Microsoft publishes it. I never see any links for it and the reference source site never comes up in my searches so I just never think of it...

Comment: That's where I went first, to the MSDN documentation and was frustrated to find there was no link directly to the source. Disappointing.

Comment: @sab669 Just google "Enumerable.cs source".  It's the first link for me. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs

Comment: @juharr Yea, I'll have to be better about remembering it. I just wasn't sure if I was missing a direct link on MSDN somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The only real difference is the name but it's important anyway. If you only want the first item use `Enumerable.First`/`FirstOrDefault`, if you want the first but maybe later also the second, third etc. then use `ElementAt`/`ElementAtOrdefault`.

The intention should be self explanatory. Readability is the  key factor here.

You can find source code [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/), for example:

[`Enumerable.ElementAt`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,7db56d44563d8761,references) and [`Enumerable.First`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,bc8ae402a61dd9d6,references)

You can see that both methods are optimized for collections that support access via index.

Answer (score 1):

They can be used interchangeably since they both are defined in `System.Linq.Enumerable`.
But here some minor differences:

1) If no results are returned, `.First` will throw an exception.

2) `.ElementAt(0)` will throw an exception if the indexer is out of bounds.

Both of these exceptions can be avoided by using `FirstOrDefault()` and/or `ElementAtOrDefault(0)`